# Type 'NSPredicate has no subscript members'

Tags: ios, swift, search

I am trying to implement a search that call its results to a database. I manage to get the database print in the console but not to access it via the search.

Here is the code I use :

```
import UIKit

class SearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

var searchPredicate = NSPredicate()
var filteredAppleProducts = [String]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController!()
var arrDataArticles: NSMutableArray!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF LIKE[c] %@", resultSearchController.searchBar.text!)

    self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

    self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.getAllArticles()
}

func getAllArticles() {
    arrDataArticles = NSMutableArray()
    arrDataArticles = ModelBD.getInstance().getAllArticles()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if self.resultSearchController.active {
        return self.filteredAppleProducts.count
    }
    else {
        return 0
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell?

    if self.resultSearchController.active {
        cell!.textLabel?.text = self.filteredAppleProducts[indexPath.row]
    }
    else {
        cell!.textLabel?.text = self.searchPredicate[indexPath.row] as! String
    }

    return cell!
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.filteredAppleProducts.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)

    let array = (self.appleProducts as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)

    self.filteredAppleProducts = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


}
```

> Type 'NSPredicate has no subscript members'

error appears on the lines

```
cell!.textLabel?.text = self.searchPredicate[indexPath.row] as! String
```

and

```
let array = (self.appleProducts as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your original answer because now the context of the answer is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an instance member in a constant like this. In your predicate you already suppose the existence of `resultSearchController`. Instead you could initialize the predicate in `viewDidLoad()` or during class initialization.

e.g.:

```
var searchPredicate: NSPredicate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF LIKE[c] %@", resultSearchController.searchBar.text!)

[...]
```

Comment: Now I have an error "Use of unresolved identifier 'searchPredicate'" on both cell!.textLabel?.text = self.searchPredicate[indexPath.row] as! String
and let array = (self.searchPredicate as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate) I understand why but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: This is a different issue. You are trying to access the predicate as if it's an array, which is not working obviously.

Comment: Can you add your changes to your original question?

Comment: Do you have an idea of how I can fix this? (I deleted the last comment as I just added a searchPredicate variable), I just updated the code above.

Comment: It says NSPredicate has no subscript members because you try to access it like a collection. You can access array (please consider a different naming) like you did, however you have to declare it as an instance variable.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to Swfit, how do I do that?

Comment: Sorry, you need to learn the basics of Swift. This is not the place for that. Please refer to Apples excellent documentation. Please also check how to use the SO Q&A correctly (see my comment to your question).

Comment: Ok, sorry for the dumb question, I tried to replace 'let' by 'var' but it displays the same error.